# Playing .wav byte array in Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, wmplib

I have encrypted audio files on my system, which i am running with my C# utility following below listed scheme

- file is decrypted and result is stored in Byte array
- i write all bytes in particular file, say, decrypted.wav
- pass decrypted.wav to function which sets IWMPMedia new media
- on closure of form file'decrypted.wav' is deleted

this scheme works great, but due to confidentiality reason i have to change it as  file can be copied and pasted elsewhere during play
i tried hidden file attribute  thing as well

i have changed scheme to

- file is decrypted and result is stored in Byte array
- byte array is passed to memory stream
- System.Media.SoundPlayer uses memory stream
  but it plays file abrubd, such as replies of intern ahead of questions

what is best way to buffer the stream

Comment: Does it play too early? Please specify "abrubd".